# Printing Reports in MS Access

Tags: database, ms-access, ms-access-2010, ms-access-2007

Is is possible to print data in MS Access that will look like cards? and aligned by columns like this? Any help would greatly be appreciated[image: datas are dynamic from MS Access Database]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, Access has a label wizard and is able to have multiple repeating rows of labels in a report.

You don’t share if you looking to have each label different, or all the labels the same. If you require the “same” label repeated over and over, then you could have code prompt the user for the number of labels and the copy the same record over and over to a temp table of which the report is based on.

So Access can most certainly produce reports in that format with multiple rows for each record. Create a report using the label wizard, and you see that you only have to lay out ONE label, and then set the number of columns etc. that you want for that one “format” to be repeated over and over.

However, if the labels are to always be the same, then of course word and its label wizard makes sense as access by default cannot print “repeating” labels of the same record over and over. So the above format is possible – it just not clear with given information if we taking about repeating the same label over and over, or that each label is to come from a table.

Answer (score 0):

I think reports on MS Access will not deliver you some printed cards as you showed above.

If you are working in MS Access with your data in it, you can use the Mail Merge functionality in MS Word to create your cards with the data you have in your MS Access database.

Check out this link how to use the Mail Merge in MS Word to print the cards: [How to create business cards in MS Word](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/170130).
The correspondent title is *Using Mail Merge and a Data File to Create and Print Many Business Cards*